# How to compare an array with a number ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I would like to compare `canIBook()` with `id` (increments) in the if statement, but it wont work.

I suspect I can't compare a number with an array, how would i go about fixing this?

The method `canIBook()` currently returns:

result: [11]

```
     const canIBook = () => {
    const no = freeSlotsList.filter((slot) => slot.booked === 1);
    const result = no.map((a) => a.id);
    return { result };
  };
```

The method with the if-statement:

```
const renderTableData = () => {
let id = 1;
const activeButton = () => {};
console.log(canIBook());
return (
  <tr>
    {days.map((val) => (
      <td>
        {timeSlot.map((n, i) => {
          if (id === canIBook()) {   //How do i make this true?
            return <h1>Works</h1>;
          } else {
            return (
              <button id={id++} className={activeButton}>
                {n} {id}
              </button>
            );
          }
        })}
      </td>
    ))}
  </tr>
);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that `canIBook` function you are actually returning an object, not an array. If you want to compare the `id` with the ids inside the array `result` you can do:

```
if (canIBook().result.includes(id)) {
```

Otherwise if you want to just return the array it would become:

```
const canIBook = () => {
 const no = freeSlotsList.filter((slot) => slot.booked === 1);
 const result = no.map((a) => a.id);
 return result;
};
```

And then:

```
if (canIBook().includes(id)) {
 //logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your code the function `canIBook` will return something like: `{ results: [1,2,3,4] }`. Then to check if the id is inside the list returned by the `canIBook` you should do something like:

```js
if (canIBook().results.includes(id)) {...}
```

Answer (score -1):

though, I don't understand the question clearly.

if you want to check if the id is in the Array you can use Array Methods such as include, filter or some.

```
if(freeSlotsList.some(slot => slot.booked == id)){
return <h1> It'works</h1>
} else {

....
}
```